# If Tamarin is running in Mozilla Firefox is it possible to run ES4 code?

Tags: javascript, firefox, ecmascript-6, mozilla, ecmascript-5

If [Tamarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamarin_(software)), the virtual machine that can run JavaScript v4 is built into Mozilla Firefox, is it possible to run ES4 in the browser? I'm tired of JS v1 and tired of ES6. I would like [AS3](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/actionscript3_overview.html)/ES4 (it is fully featured and farther along than ES6).

Read [this](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/actionscript3_overview.html) to understand why I'd like to run AS3 in the browser.

More info on [Tamarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamarin_(software)).
More info on [Tamarin](https://hg.mozilla.org/tamarin-redux).
More info on [Tamarin](https://hg.mozilla.org/tamarin-redux/file/tip/esc/src/main.es).
More info on [EcmaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript).
More info on [ActionScript3](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/actionscript3_overview.html) (based on ES3 and ES4).
More info on [ActionScript 3 Language Reference](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html).

Comment: But ES4 was abandoned, right? No such spec exists

Comment: There are two platforms that it applies to. The browser and the Flash Platform. Adobe adopted the ES4 spec and made into a fully featured language that runs in the Flash Player or in HTML pages in Adobe AIR. It is in use today and the virtual machine is open source and donated to Mozilla (see links above). IIRC it was dismissed by browser vendors at the time bc it was deemed to be too advanced for 2006. But it's now 2018.

Comment: What does ES4 have that ES2018 does not?

Comment: I didn't see ES2018 on the wikipedia page I've linked so I can't compare but comparing it to ES2017 then it looks like AS3 has method closures, sealed classes, packages, namespaces, new primitive types and E4X. BTW There are debates on E4X. I don't care who likes it or doesn't. Servers and applications all over the world use XML and E4X has it's place.

Comment: If the browser vendors want to bring the AS3 devs into their fold being able to use AS3 (ES3 and ES4) would be a huge advantage.

Answer (score 1):

> If Tamarin, the virtual machine that can run JavaScript v4 is built into Mozilla Firefox

It isn't. See the Wikipedia page you linked to:

> There **were** plans to use Tamarin as part of Mozilla 2[7] (and therefore Firefox 4).

and

> it has not replaced SpiderMonkey as the JavaScript engine of Mozilla applications

---

> Is it possible to run ES4 in the browser?

No. [ES4 was abandoned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#4th_Edition_(abandoned)).

Some features were adopted into Harmony and have made it into newer versions of ES.

Comment: It looks like it is in their repository. However I'm not sure if its linked into their build. That is why I asked. https://hg.mozilla.org/tamarin-redux

Comment: See, again, the quotes above. Also note that that repository says the last change was over half a decade ago.

Comment: I've read it. I thought it was linked in somewhere for the JIT. It would be interesting to see if SpiderMonkey could be made to support AS3.

Answer (score 1):

The premise is wrong, Tamarin doesn't run in Mozilla Firefox. As [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamarin_(software)) states,

> The only part of Tamarin used in modern Mozilla applications (i.e. Firefox 3.5+) via SpiderMonkey is NanoJIT, a module that is used to generate native code when performing just-in-time compilation.

ECMAScript 4 specification was abandoned, so there's no support for it in browsers.

If ES6 doesn't cover all expected ES4 features (e.g. it doesn't provide type checking), the possible alternatives are TypeScript and Dart. TypeScript is basically ES2018 with type checks and several own features, it doesn't require a developer to learn a new language. Neither of them can run natively in browsers, but Dart has [Dartium](https://webdev.dartlang.org/tools/dartium) to run the code in VM and skip transpilation step.

Comment: OK so part of Tamarin is in Mozilla products? Is it Tamarin or a DLL that was once part of Tamarin?

Comment: It's a library, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/Nanojit . It's no longer used in Mozilla products, but possibly parts of it are still in use.